# How to structure data in Redis for keyword pattern prefix search?

Tags: redis

Just starting to play with Redis, need a bit of help.
I’m trying to figure out the best way to structure the data to address the following use case:

Here’s the pseudo code of why I’d like to achieve:

```
saveKeyword(keyword) {
  if (keyword exist) 
    save "keyword":score=score++"
  else 
    save "keyword":score=1
}

getKeywords(pattern) {
  find all keywords containing a word starting with "pattern"
  return top 10 matching keywords 
}
```

- data stored are multi word, alpha numeric only keywords
- each keyword needs to have its score incremented on every save (the score represents how many times it was saved)
- on read, only the top 10 keywords containing at least one word starting with the search pattern need to be returned

The only way I know how to cover all the above requirements is by using "KEYS pattern" which can be very computationally intense (https://redis.io/commands/keys/).

Can anyone please help me figure out the best way to store and retrieve the data?

Answer (score 0):

You could use RediSearch (`FT.`-commands).

- Create a index with `FT.CREATE keywordIdx ON hash PREFIX 1 kw: SCHEMA keywords TAG`. This will use a tag field for you keywords. You can store multiple words in a `TAG` separated by `,` (default separator). The `PREFIX 1 kw:` says to only index keys that starts with `kw`.
- Insert your keywords where all words are part of the key and also in the tag field `HSET kw:word1:word2:word3 score 1 keywords "word1,word2,word3"`.
- Search the index with something like `FT.SEARCH keywordIdx "@keywords:{ word1 | word3 }" LIMIT 0 10`. This will search for all keywords that contains either `word1` or `word2` and return 10. You could use `"@keywords:{ word1 } @keywords:{ word3 }"` to search for keywords that contains both `word1` and `word3`.
- Use `HGET` to get score and then `HSET` to set new score. If you want to avoid race conditions, you could use `MULTI` and `EXEC` for transactions. Or store the score in a separate key with `SET kw:score:word1:word2:word3 1` and then use `INCR` to increment the score.

[Read more about RediSearch using tag fields](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/advanced-concepts/tags/)